# How to include intellij code analyzer in maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, code-analysis, intellij-plugin

I want to use the IntelliJ code analyzer profile while running the maven build. We are not able to use sonar due to some compliance issues.

Comment: You can run code inspections from the command line as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html .

Comment: We are trying command line only but I want to run it whenever we do a maven build. Any way if the same can be handled during maven build.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov When I am running the inspect command on other system I am getting below error Descriptions are missed for tools: UpdateTransitionLabel, TransitionPropertiesLabel

Comment: Would also be interested in this, if possible. :)